# rmagick installation

Tags: imagemagick

Hi I have big problem with rmabick installation on CenotOS 5.5 I installed ImageMagick from source and tes it from line command and works ok. What is wrong. Please somebody help me !

[root$server.com RMagick-2.13.1]# ruby setup.rb
---> lib
---> lib/rvg
<--- lib/rvg
<--- lib
---> ext
---> ext/RMagick
/usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/src/rmagicks/RMagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** /usr/local/src/rmagicks/RMagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=/usr/local/src/rmagicks/RMagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in`try_cpp'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in`block in checking_for'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in`checking_for'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
        from /usr/local/src/rmagicks/RMagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/extconf.rb:193:in`'
setup.rb:655:in `command': system("/usr/local/bin/ruby" "/usr/local/src/rmagicks/RMagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/extconf.rb") failed (RuntimeError)
        from setup.rb:660:in`ruby'
        from setup.rb:1238:in `extconf'
        from setup.rb:1230:in`config_dir_ext'
        from setup.rb:1532:in `block in traverse'
        from setup.rb:1549:in`dive_into'
        from setup.rb:1530:in `traverse'
        from setup.rb:1534:in`block (2 levels) in traverse'
        from setup.rb:1533:in `each'
        from setup.rb:1533:in`block in traverse'
        from setup.rb:1549:in `dive_into'
        from setup.rb:1530:in`traverse'
        from setup.rb:1524:in `block in exec_task_traverse'
        from setup.rb:1519:in`each'
        from setup.rb:1519:in `exec_task_traverse'
        from setup.rb:1223:in`exec_config'
        from setup.rb:991:in `exec_config'
        from setup.rb:812:in`invoke'
        from setup.rb:772:in `invoke'
        from setup.rb:1578:in`'

------------------------------------ end ruby setup.rb ------------------------------------

Below logs from mkmf.log file

checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

---

find_executable: checking for gcc... -------------------- yes

---

find_executable: checking for Magick-config... -------------------- yes

---

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... -------------------- yes

---

checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... -------------------- yes

---

"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/src/rmagicks/RMagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick  -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick  -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick -fopenmp conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/lib     -L/usr/local/lib -lMagickCore -ltiff -lfreetype -ljpeg -lpng -lbz2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lpthread   -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_write_fn@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_header_ver@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_gAMA@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_bKGD@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_keep_unknown_chunks@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_tRNS@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_read_update_info@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_oFFs@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_free_data@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_text@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_permit_mng_features@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_valid@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_bKGD@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_iCCP@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_cHRM@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_compression_level@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_invalid@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_warning@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_PLTE@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_sRGB@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_cHRM@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_malloc@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_compression_strategy@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_write_end@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_sBIT@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_y_offset_pixels@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_free@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_write_row@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_gAMA@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_write_info@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct_2@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_sRGB@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_PLTE@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_libpng_ver@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_interlace_handling@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_error_ptr@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_error@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_buffer_size@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_pHYs@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_compression_mem_level@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_read_row@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_IHDR@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_user_chunk_ptr@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_write_info_before_PLTE@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_sig_bytes@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_read_end@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_get_x_offset_pixels@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct_2@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_destroy_write_struct@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_get_pHYs@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_iCCP@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_filter@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to`png_set_text@PNG12_0'
/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore.so: undefined reference to `png_set_read_user_chunk_fn@PNG12_0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */